# Error while installing emacs-eclimd "Cannot open load file: auto-complete"

Tags: package

When I install emacs-eclimd, I get two errors

```
Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/ac-emacs-eclim-source.el at Thu Oct 23 09:47:40 2014
Entering directory `/home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/'
ac-emacs-eclim-source.el:33:1:Error: Cannot open load file: auto-complete

Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/company-emacs-eclim.el at Thu Oct 23 09:47:40 2014
company-emacs-eclim.el:34:1:Error: Cannot open load file: company
```

and a bunch of warnings.

I can't figure out  the output of compilation by searching. Do I need to do something to fix the errors and warnings and others? 
I wonder if I have successfully installed the package? Thanks.

The complete output of compilation is:

```
Leaving directory `/home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207'

Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/ac-emacs-eclim-source.el at Thu Oct 23 09:47:40 2014
Entering directory `/home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/'
ac-emacs-eclim-source.el:33:1:Error: Cannot open load file: auto-complete

Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/company-emacs-eclim.el at Thu Oct 23 09:47:40 2014
company-emacs-eclim.el:34:1:Error: Cannot open load file: company

Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/eclim-ant.el at Thu Oct 23 09:47:40 2014

In eclim-ant-validate:
eclim-ant.el:91:8:Warning: `beginning-of-buffer' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only

In end of data:
eclim-ant.el:105:21:Warning: the function
    `eclim--convert-find-result-to-string' is not known to be defined.

Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/eclim-completion.el at Thu Oct 23 09:47:40 2014

In eclim--completion-candidates-filter:
eclim-completion.el:75:52:Warning: function `search' from cl package called at
    runtime
eclim-completion.el:76:51:Warning: function `search' from cl package called at
    runtime

In eclim--completion-action-java:
eclim-completion.el:183:74:Warning: reference to free variable
    `yas-minor-mode'

In eclim--completion-action-xml:
eclim-completion.el:199:61:Warning: reference to free variable
    `yas-minor-mode'

In eclim--completion-action-default:
eclim-completion.el:206:56:Warning: reference to free variable
    `yas-minor-mode'

In eclim--completion-documentation:
eclim-completion.el:234:100:Warning: function `find' from cl package called at
    runtime

In end of data:
eclim-completion.el:239:1:Warning: the function `yas/expand-snippet' is not
    known to be defined.

Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/eclim-java.el at Thu Oct 23 09:47:40 2014

In eclim--java-parse-method-signature:
eclim-java.el:156:44:Warning: `flet' is an obsolete macro (as of 24.3); use
    either `cl-flet' or `cl-letf'.

In eclim-soft-revert-imports:
eclim-java.el:427:4:Warning: `flet' is an obsolete macro (as of 24.3); use
    either `cl-flet' or `cl-letf'.
eclim-java.el:427:4:Warning: `beginning-of-buffer' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only
eclim-java.el:433:36:Warning: `end-of-buffer' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only

In eclim-java-import:
eclim-java.el:460:4:Warning: `beginning-of-buffer' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only

In format-type:
eclim-java.el:484:106:Warning: function `mapcan' from cl package called at
    runtime

In eclim-java-implement:
eclim-java.el:517:108:Warning: `flet' is an obsolete macro (as of 24.3); use
    either `cl-flet' or `cl-letf'.
eclim-java.el:523:30:Warning: function `reduce' from cl package called at
    runtime
eclim-java.el:506:77:Warning: function `mapcan' from cl package called at
    runtime
eclim-java.el:518:77:Warning: function `remove-if-not' from cl package called
    at runtime
eclim-java.el:527:86:Warning: function `find' from cl package called at
    runtime
eclim-java.el:527:128:Warning: function `subseq' from cl package called at
    runtime
eclim-java.el:527:128:Warning: function `remove-if-not' from cl package called
    at runtime
eclim-java.el:529:66:Warning: function `find' from cl package called at
    runtime
eclim-java.el:529:66:Warning: function `remove-if' from cl package called at
    runtime
eclim-java.el:529:98:Warning: function `remove-if' from cl package called at
    runtime

In eclim-java-correct:
eclim-java.el:578:13:Warning: assignment to free variable
    `eclim-corrections-previous-window-config'
eclim-java.el:580:13:Warning: assignment to free variable
    `eclim-correction-command-info'

In eclim-java-correct-choose:
eclim-java.el:599:15:Warning: `string-to-int' is an obsolete function (as of
    22.1); use `string-to-number' instead.
eclim-java.el:601:19:Warning: reference to free variable
    `eclim-correction-command-info'
eclim-java.el:602:35:Warning: reference to free variable
    `eclim-corrections-previous-window-config'

In eclim-java-correct-quit:
eclim-java.el:619:29:Warning: reference to free variable
    `eclim-corrections-previous-window-config'

In eclim--java-show-documentation-and-format:
eclim-java.el:656:19:Warning: reference to free variable
    `eclim-java-show-documentation-history'
eclim-java.el:656:19:Warning: assignment to free variable
    `eclim-java-show-documentation-history'

In eclim-java-show-documentation-follow-link:
eclim-java.el:714:35:Warning: function `some' from cl package called at
    runtime

In eclim--java-show-documentation-go-back:
eclim-java.el:722:16:Warning: reference to free variable
    `eclim-java-show-documentation-history'
eclim-java.el:722:16:Warning: assignment to free variable
    `eclim-java-show-documentation-history'

In end of data:
eclim-java.el:727:1:Warning: the function `yas/expand-snippet' is not known to
    be defined.

Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/eclim-maven.el at Thu Oct 23 09:47:40 2014

Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/eclim-problems.el at Thu Oct 23 09:47:41 2014

In eclim-problems-highlight:
eclim-problems.el:170:133:Warning: function `remove-if-not' from cl package
    called at runtime

In eclim--problems-get-current-problem:
eclim-problems.el:189:24:Warning: function `find-if' from cl package called at
    runtime

In eclim--with-problems-list:
eclim-problems.el:210:15:Warning: function `gensym' from cl package called at
    runtime

In eclim-problems-buffer-refresh:
eclim-problems.el:229:90:Warning: function `remove-if-not' from cl package
    called at runtime
eclim-problems.el:229:90:Warning: function `remove-if-not' from cl package
    called at runtime
eclim-problems.el:229:90:Warning: function `remove-if-not' from cl package
    called at runtime
eclim-problems.el:229:90:Warning: function `remove-if-not' from cl package
    called at runtime

In eclim--problems-cleanup-filename:
eclim-problems.el:232:61:Warning: reference to free variable `problem'

In eclim--problems-buffer-redisplay:
eclim-problems.el:258:21:Warning: Use `with-current-buffer' rather than
    save-excursion+set-buffer

In eclim--problems-filtered:
eclim-problems.el:292:4:Warning: function `remove-if-not' from cl package
    called at runtime

In eclim--insert-problem:
eclim-problems.el:296:70:Warning: function `position' from cl package called
    at runtime

In eclim-problems-next:
eclim-problems.el:387:21:Warning: reference to free variable `hl-line-overlay'

In eclim-problems-previous:
eclim-problems.el:396:21:Warning: reference to free variable `hl-line-overlay'

In end of data:
eclim-problems.el:446:1:Warning: the function `hl-line-move' is not known to
    be defined.

Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/eclim-project.el at Thu Oct 23 09:47:41 2014

In eclim--project-buffer-refresh:
eclim-project.el:103:17:Warning: `goto-line' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only

In eclim--project-get-marked:
eclim-project.el:133:45:Warning: `beginning-of-buffer' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only

In eclim-project-create:
eclim-project.el:251:62:Warning: assignment to free variable `target'
eclim-project.el:251:77:Warning: assignment to free variable `application'
eclim-project.el:252:50:Warning: reference to free variable `target'
eclim-project.el:252:50:Warning: reference to free variable `application'

In eclim-project-mark-all:
eclim-project.el:295:4:Warning: `beginning-of-buffer' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only

In eclim-project-unmark-all:
eclim-project.el:307:4:Warning: `beginning-of-buffer' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only

In eclim-project-goto:
eclim-project.el:319:33:Warning: function `find' from cl package called at
    runtime

In eclim-project-mode:
eclim-project.el:370:33:Warning: `beginning-of-buffer' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only

Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/eclim.el at Thu Oct 23 09:47:41 2014

In eclim--make-command:
eclim.el:153:61:Warning: function `reduce' from cl package called at runtime

In eclim--call-process-async:
eclim.el:196:71:Warning: function `find' from cl package called at runtime
eclim.el:206:118:Warning: function `remove-if' from cl package called at
    runtime

In eclim--args-contains:
eclim.el:224:84:Warning: function `find' from cl package called at runtime

In eclim--project-name:
eclim.el:345:39:Warning: `labels' is an obsolete macro (as of 24.3); use
    `cl-labels' instead.

In eclim--find-file:
eclim.el:362:8:Warning: `beginning-of-buffer' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only
eclim.el:370:10:Warning: `beginning-of-buffer' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only

In eclim--find-display-results:
eclim.el:375:125:Warning: function `remove-if' from cl package called at
    runtime

In eclim--visit-declaration:
eclim.el:401:46:Warning: `goto-line' used from Lisp code
That command is designed for interactive use only

In eclim--accepted-filename-p:
eclim.el:494:8:Warning: function `member-if' from cl package called at runtime

In end of data:
eclim.el:545:1:Warning: the function `archive-extract' is not known to be
    defined.

Compiling file /home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/eclimd.el at Thu Oct 23 09:47:41 2014

In wait-eclimd-start:
eclimd.el:112:54:Warning: assignment to free variable `eclimd-port'
eclimd.el:113:5:Warning: reference to free variable `eclimd-port'
```

---

There is error when running `(require 'eclimd)`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "eclimd")
  require(eclimd)
  eval((require (quote eclimd)) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

Comment: Does `(require 'eclimd)` throw an error?

Comment: Right now your title is quite general and your question quite specific. Both are fine, but you change one to match the other. I would suggest editing the title.

Comment: @caisah: I think so. see my update.

Comment: @Tim What about `(require 'eclim)`? And if it doesn't find `auto-complete` try to install it manually, or check if installed.

Comment: @caisah: It is strange that `(require 'eclimd)` now output `eclimd`. Does it mean that it is successful?

Comment: but still the compilation errors and warnings.

Comment: Does M-x `start-eclimd` also work?

Answer (score 1):

Put the directory containing `autocomplete.el` in your `load-path`. Likewise, for `company.el`.  E.g. if that directory is `/home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/foobar/` then do this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/tim/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/foobar/")
```

Then `(require 'autocomplete)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `company` mode you don't have to fix it. The error about `auto-complete` could stem from having `(require 'ac-emacs-eclim-source)` and `(ac-emacs-eclim-config)` in your `.emacs`. If so, make sure that your `emacs-eclim` configuration takes place *after* your auto-complete configuration.

If you don't have `auto-complete` installed use the instructions [above](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2504/2670).